# How to use msiexec.exe to remove a Windows installer

Tags: windows-installer

We have a Windows installer package, `sample.msi`. To install the package we are using

```
msiexec /i sample.exec /qr
```

To uninstall the same package, the below code is used.

```
msiexec /x sample.exec /qr
```

When we use `/x` it deletes all the files in the associated directory which is created. We want to **retain all the contents** in the directory. How is that possible?

Comment: Copy the directory contents into another location before uninstalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Windows Installer removes all the files installed by the package, except the ones created after the installation finished. If you want to keep the files installed after uninstall the most simple solution is to mark their components as permanent, in the [Component table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You can edit the the MSI directly using Orca tool, which is free, to add the flags documented in the link from my answer, for the entries from Component table. Or if the MSI is built with a more advanced setup authoring tool you can probably set this flag very easily from that tool, its usually available as a checkbox option you just need to check within its user-guide.